# Merging field attributes in table using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table

I have a polygon file that contains landowner data for parcels. Problem is, many parcels have more than one owner, so my attribute table can show 3-5 landowners per parcel, all with separate polygons. I'll attach a screenshot, where I edited for the sake of privacy reasons (very quickly) the parcel numbers/land owner names.

[image]

As you can see, many different rows are attributed to the same parcel. I'd like to merge these together, and have the landowners all in a same line. So for example, the first row would state "1, Transportation Services, John Smith, Jones and CO", and the second entry would then be "2, Lebkov, Trust Co., Fred Doe, Beyonce". Ideally, the LandOwners would be in a new field named MergedOwners or something along those lines.  I tried to write code with it in the field calculator, and it came up with an error each time. There are also way more entries to this site but just showed two examples, otherwise I would fix it manually. This will likely be a recurring topic with my work, I'd like to learn how to do it properly now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [dissolve tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm).

Set the Dissolve Field to your "parcel number" field and set your "landowner" field as Statistics Fields with the Concatenate option (don't forget to set the Concatenation Separator parameter).

If you have other fields that you want to keep, add them as statistic field with appropriate option.